# How to name highest level of lists created within a purr function

Tags: r, purrr

I am using purrr to iteratively apply functions to sf objects based on different aoi,  and store the outputs in lists, however I cannot assign names to the top level of nested lists.  I don't think think the sf objects are relevant to the problem, but including a sf based example just in case. IN my desried output I could query the list by region name to pull out both the region and state sublists to pass to other mapping functions, and the second mapview call at the end of code would produce same result as the call using index numbers on the same list.

```
#set things up
library(spData)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(mapview)

STATES <- spData::us_states %>%
  mutate(REGION=as.character(REGION))


REGIONS <- STATES %>%
  group_by(REGION) %>%
    summarise() %>%
  group_by(REGION) %>%
  group_split(.keep = T) %>%
    set_names(.,nm=map(.,\(x)first(x$REGION)))


REGIONS_INTERSECT <- REGIONS %>%
  map( \(x) st_intersection(STATES, x))


REGION_NAMES <- as.character(STATES$REGION) %>%
  unique()


##desired format but top level list not named


OUT_LIST <- map(REGION_NAMES, \(x){
  REGION_LIST <- REGIONS[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="Region")
  STATE_LIST <- REGIONS_INTERSECT[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="State")
  
  OUTPUT <-  c(REGION_LIST, STATE_LIST )
    
  
  return(OUTPUT)
  
}) 

##changes lower level names 


OUT_LIST <- map(REGION_NAMES, \(x){
  REGION_LIST <- REGIONS[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="Region")
  STATE_LIST <- REGIONS_INTERSECT[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="State")
  
  OUTPUT <-  c(REGION_LIST, STATE_LIST ) %>%
    set_names(.,nm=x)
  
  
  return(OUTPUT)
  
}) 



##alos changes lower level names 


OUT_LIST <- map(REGION_NAMES, \(x){
  REGION_LIST <- REGIONS[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="Region")
  STATE_LIST <- REGIONS_INTERSECT[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="State")
  
  x <-  c(REGION_LIST, STATE_LIST ) 
  
  
  return(OUTPUT)
  
}) 

##only changes one lower level names 


OUT_LIST <- map(REGION_NAMES, \(x){
  REGION_LIST <- REGIONS[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="Region")
  STATE_LIST <- REGIONS_INTERSECT[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="State")
  
  OUTPUT <-  c(REGION_LIST, STATE_LIST ) 
  
   names(OUTPUT)<-x
  
  return(OUTPUT)
  
}) 





###in desired output these two functions woudl have same output

mapview(OUT_LIST[[1]][[1]])+mapview(OUT_LIST[[1]][[2]], col.regions="red")


mapview(OUT_LIST[["South"]][["Region"]])+mapview(OUT_LIST[["South"]][["State"]], col.regions="red")
```

Comment: The answer by @zephryl  supplied below solves my problem, but I am also curious if there are other ways I could explicitly name lists at different levels without affecting other levels.  It seems like the sort of thing that can be done multiple ways and I was feeling pretty frustrated I couldn't figure out any.

Comment: You could also do `names(OUT_LIST) <- REGION_NAMES` or `OUT_LIST <- set_names(OUT_LIST, REGION_NAMES)`. If I'm understanding your question / comment.

Comment: Now I feel even dumber, I was leaning towards options that calculated names based on the output data `set_names(nm = map_chr(.x = ., ~ first(.x$REGION)))`   in case the  order of lists was altered somehow, however this works great.  Going back now I see that my issue was not iterating deep enough in the lists and this achieves the same result `set_names(., nm=map( .,\(x) x) %>%
              map(., \(y) y$Region) %>%
              map_chr(.,\(z) first(z$REGION)))` thanks for helping me work this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input vector is named, the output of `map()` will have the same names. So you can just name your vector of regions with `purrr::set_names(REGION_NAMES)` (or `setNames(nm = REGION_NAMES)`):

```r
OUT_LIST <- map(set_names(REGION_NAMES), \(x){
  REGION_LIST <- REGIONS[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="Region")
  STATE_LIST <- REGIONS_INTERSECT[x] %>%
    set_names(nm="State")
  
  c(REGION_LIST, STATE_LIST)
}) 

names(OUT_LIST)
# "South"    "West"     "Norteast" "Midwest"
```